# How to have different name for person in mail and phone?

Tags: settings, email, contacts

**TL;DR:** I would like to have different name for e-mails sent to my wife and different name when my wife calls me

Longer read. Since I don't want to make my family public, just accept the fact that I married `Jane Doe` and we decided to keep our "maiden" name, so she remained `Doe` even after the marriage.

As most people do, I stored her under `My Darling` in my phone. Now comes the fun part. When I send mails from Outlook.com or my phone, the e-mail looks kinda like this:

```
From: Pavel.Janicek 
To: BigBuilder co.
Cc: My Darling
Subject: Re: New house inquiry

I agree with the prices, and also we are willing to throw in extra 500 000 USD for the garden

Sent from my Windows Phone
```

<sup>* Not actual mail</sup>

It obviously does not look any profesional.

The funniest part is:

- If I store my wife under `Jane Janicek` to show she is my wife, it will not be true
- If I store her under `Jane Doe` no one will know she is my wife

And since I found several phones and successfully returned by calling contacts like "Mom", "Dad" or "My Darling" I would like to keep some info on my phone "who to call if this phone is found"

Is there a way out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the easiest solution would be to have two separate contacts, one with you wifes maiden name and her e-mail address and one with her "nickname" and her phone number. You could try linking those contacts but I'm not sure how for example an incomming call would be announced - something to try out.

If you're worried about loosing your phone, there are several nice apps that let you [display your contact information for example on the lockscreen](http://www.windowsphone.com/de-de/store/app/lost-phone-screen/97f0fdcf-ecf6-44a0-b698-08436e86edaa) or on a tile on your startscreen.

Comment: I have linked accounts for her now. And seems like that the "phone" account has the highest priority. Time to unlink them... Thanks for advice